# JSON.NET Serializes Empty JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am using `MetadataType` to define Json.NET attributes for the following type, then serializing it using Json.NET inside its `ToString()` method:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public interface ICell
    {
        int Id { get; }
    }
    public interface IEukaryote
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ICell> Cells { get; }
        string GenericName { get; }
    }
    public sealed partial class PlantCell
        : ICell
    {
        public int Id => 12324;
    }
    public sealed partial class Plant
        : IEukaryote
    {
        private readonly System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _valuesDict;
        public Plant()
        {
            _valuesDict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
            var cells = new System.Collections.Generic.List<PlantCell>();
            cells.Add(new PlantCell());
            _valuesDict["Cells"] = cells;
            _valuesDict["GenericName"] = "HousePlant";
        }
        public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ICell> Cells => _valuesDict["Cells"] as System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ICell>;
        public string GenericName => _valuesDict["GenericName"] as string;
        public int SomethingIDoNotWantSerialized => 99999;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this,
                new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                }
            );
        }
    }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MetadataType(typeof(PlantMetadata))]
    public sealed partial class Plant
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObject(Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
        internal sealed class PlantMetadata
        {
            [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]
            public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ICell> Cells;
            [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]
            public string GenericName;
            //...
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var plant = new Plant();
            System.Console.WriteLine(System.String.Format("Output is {0}", plant.ToString()));
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that `Plant.ToString()` will return '{}'. Why is that? It was working before. The only change I made was in `PlantMetadata` where I altered the `MemberSerialization` to OptIn instead of OptOut, as I had less properties I wanted included than left out.

Comment: Copy and paste into new VS project.

Comment: As an aside: Using the default of OptOut then adding JsonIgnore attributes to properties I do not serialized, will result in those properties being serialized regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated by Newtonsoft in [this issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/405), [`MetadataTypeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) attributes are in fact supported by Json.NET.  However, it appears that Json.NET requires that the [`MetadataClassType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.metadataclasstype(v=vs.110).aspx) members must be properties when the corresponding "real" members are properties, and fields when the corresponding "real" members are fields.  Thus, if I define your `Plant` type as follows, with two properties and one field to be serialized:

```
public sealed partial class Plant : IEukaryote
{
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ICell> Cells { get { return (_valuesDict["Cells"] as System.Collections.IEnumerable).Cast<ICell>(); } }
    public string GenericName { get { return _valuesDict["GenericName"] as string; } }
    public string FieldIWantSerialized;
    public int SomethingIDoNotWantSerialized { get { return 99999; } }

    // Remainder as before.
```

Then the `PlantMetadata` must also have two properties and one field for them to be serialized successfully:

```
//Metadata.cs
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MetadataType(typeof(PlantMetadata))]
public sealed partial class Plant
{
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    internal sealed class PlantMetadata
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public IEnumerable<ICell> Cells { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string GenericName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string FieldIWantSerialized;
    }
}
```

If I make `Cells` or `GenericName` be fields, or `FieldIWantSerialized` be a property, then they do not get opted into serialization.

Sample working  [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1wObQQ).

Note that, in addition, I have found that the `MetadataClassType` properties apparently must have the same *return type* as the real properties.  If I change your `PlantMetadata` as follows:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
internal sealed class PlantMetadata
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public object Cells { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public object GenericName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public object FieldIWantSerialized;
}
```

Then only `FieldIWantSerialized` is serialized, not the properties.  [.Net Fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bXcCrj) showing this behavior.  This may be a Newtonsoft issue; as stated in the Microsoft documentation [Defining Attributes in Metadata Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664465(v=pandp.50).aspx):

> The actual type of these properties is not important, and is ignored
>   by the compiler. The accepted approach is to declare them all as of
>   type Object.

If it matters, you could [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) about the return type restriction to Newtonsoft - or report an issue asking that details of their support for `MetadataTypeAttribute` be more fully documented.