# Associate JsonSerializer instructions with a data-model partial class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, json.net

There is the [MetadataTypeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the metadata class to associate with a data model class. So, I can define metadata, that help render HTML controls in an MVC application, within an associated class from another file. For example:

**User.cs**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
public partial class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

**MetaData.cs**

```
public partial class UserMetaData
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Your Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Your Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Is there similar way to define [JsonProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attributes for my model's properties in another file?

Comment: Have you tried it?  What was the result?  Json.NET does support `[MetadataType]`, e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45045881/3744182) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10306177/3744182) for examples of the two being used in tandem.

Comment: In fact, it just works.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/bUusfe

Comment: @dbc, is the answer so obvious?! Thank you!